# Iphone 4 Simulator, Set Background Image?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I noticed on Xcode 3.2.3 that of the three simulators available both the iPhone(water drops) and iPad(night sky) show background images. Is there a way to add a few photos to Photos so that I can set one as a backdrop.

NB: I tried dragging an image to Safari in the simulator and then clicking/holding and saving but the image does not show up in Photos.

Gary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapping and holding on an image viewed in Safari allows you to add the selected image to the Photo application. When the message pop-up appears choose "Save Image". Quit Safari and go to the Photo application. The image should be in the camera roll.

I have tried this technique before and it has always worked for me.

Comment: Hi Steve, just tried this again as you stated and it works just fine, its funny as I tried this before posting with no luck. Quitting Xcode and relaunching the simulator seems to have cleared things out.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting some images in the following directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

Create the `100APPLE` directory if it doesn't already exist. Then add some images in the format of:

```
IMG_0000.JPG
IMG_0001.JPG
IMG_0002.JPG
IMG_0003.JPG
```

I think this might be case sensitive as well.